# Scroll one element when the body is scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

Is it possible using jQuery to simulate the scrolling of an element when the user scrolls anywhere on the page? I have a div that is 100% height and uses `overflow: scroll` to display a scrollbar. The body of the page does not have a scrollbar as it is 100% height as well. I would like to make it so that when the user trys to scroll anywhere on the page, the div scrolls. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+      +                   +       +
+      +                   +       +
+ Left +      Content      + Right +
+      +                   +       +
+      +                   +       +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Consider you want to scroll the content, not the left and right panel. you can use the position:fixed for left and right panel.

so whenever u will scroll the page it will scroll only content panel, not left & right panels as they are fixed.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    html,body,div
    {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    }
    #left_panel, #right_panel
    {
        width:19%;
        display:inline-block;
        background-color:#22435D;
        height:50%;
        position:fixed;
    }
    #center_panel
    {
        margin-left:20%;
        width:60%;
        display:inline-block;   
        height:150%;
        background-color:white;
        color:#22435D;
        border:1px solid #22435D;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="left_panel">
    </div>
    <div id="center_panel">
        you content goes here
        <br/>
        you content goes here
        <br/>
        you content goes here
        <br/>
        you content goes here
        <br/>
        you content goes here
        <br/>
        you content goes here
        <br/>
        you content goes here
        <br/>
        you content goes here
    </div>
    <div id="right_panel">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

now if you scroll the page it will scroll the center panel only.